# Windows 10 Crossed Network Streams

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-update

This is very bizarre, but it's happened twice now, so I want to see if anyone else has run into it.

On Windows 10, after an automatic Windows Update, I am getting crossing network streams, meaning that one connection ends up receiving data from a different active connection.

I know it sounds crazy, but I've tested it extensively and can reproduce it. For example, I have a server that will return an HTTP request with 100 MB of whatever letter I ask for, repeated over and over and over. So if I ask for `A`, I will get a 100 MB file with `A`s.

My test was to run 4 simultaneous requests, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

My `A` file has a lot of `A`s (about 87 million, when it should have 105 million), but also has some `B`s, `C`s, and `D`s. It also has some unidentified binary data, an HTTP response header from `.stackoverflow.com` (I was searching for similar problems while the test was running), what looks like some GZipped data, and some network data that looks like it was from my router. The `B` file has all of the other letters and some of the same HTTP headers as the `A` file, but mostly consists of `B`s (80M out of 105M). The `C` file is the worst, at only 18M `C`s out of 105M. The majority of the data is binary gibberish with some JSON response headers and what might be an SSL certificate. The `D` file is the best (98M/105M) but is still garbled.

Adding it up across the 4 files, `A`, `B`, and `D` are within 200k of the right number, the rest probably corrupting other requests, which I sometimes see as corrupted image files or Javascript that doesn't work correctly. I don't know where the `C`s went, but I hope those requests weren't important. All of the files are the right size (meaning `wget` is getting the correct `Content-Length` header and is respecting it).

The problem is consistent across browsers, command line tools, etc. It becomes apparent because images get corrupted and random Javascript errors (from corrupted JS files) start popping up. Both times the problem has come up, it has been immediately after a Windows Update. Rolling back the updates does not fix it.

The network interface is an ASUS USB-N53 adapter with up-to-date drivers.

The problem also presents with some disk errors. `sfc /scannow` returns:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
>   of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
>   example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
>   supported in offline servicing scenarios.

The recommended `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` succeeds, but `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` returns an error:

> Error: 0x800f081f
>
> The source files could not be found.
>   Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

I've tried building a source ISO as described in all the forums that address this problem, but haven't gotten it to "RestoreHealth" properly.

Again, I know this is a very bizarre problem, but I'm stumped, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction? Last time it was solved by a Windows reinstall, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I'm going to bet on antivirus software gone nuts.

Comment: No anti-virus software installed, except Windows Defender, which is standard on Windows 10.